# .net XPTable don't show all rows

Tags: .net, vb.net, listview, social-networking

Hy everyone I'm new here. I have a problem I'm building a Vb .Net chat program and I need to implement a chatlistview just like Skype chatlistview or Facebook chatlistview I can't use .net default listview because all rows are supposed to have same height so it can't display different sizes messages I've found on the web the XPTable it's cool but it don't display all the rows the last rows can't be scrolled so please if someone could help me finding a control to display chat messages or even help me with XPTable I'll be thankful I've been stucked for 3 months .
Excuse my poor English waiting for a reply

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

@nitish this is my code to fill the XPTable

```
Private Sub fillChat(ByVal messageList As List(Of ChatExtraData))

    If messageList.Count > 0 Then

        table.BeginUpdate()
        table.EnableWordWrap = True
        table.SelectionStyle = SelectionStyle.Grid
        table.GridLines = GridLines.Rows

        Dim col1 As TextColumn = New TextColumn("", 200)

        table.ColumnModel = New ColumnModel(New Column() {col1})

        Dim model As TableModel = New TableModel()
        Dim cpt As Integer = 0
        For Each msg In messageList

            Try
                Dim precedentMsg As Row = model.Rows.Item(cpt - 1)
                Dim messagePrecedent As ChatExtraData = precedentMsg.Tag

                If (msg.senderId <> messagePrecedent.senderId) Then
                    Dim header As Row = addHead(msg.HeaderText, msg)
                    model.Rows.Add(header)
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                Dim header As Row = addHead(msg.HeaderText, msg)
                model.Rows.Add(header)
            End Try

            Dim ligne As Row = addMsg(msg.MinorText, msg)

            model.Rows.Add(ligne)
            cpt = cpt + 1
        Next

        messageList.Clear()
        table.TableModel = model
        table.EndUpdate()

    End If

End Sub

Function addMsg(ByVal txt As String, ByVal extra As ChatExtraData) As Row
    Dim row As Row
    Dim cell As Cell

    row = New Row()
    Dim texte As String = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(txt)

    cell = New Cell(texte)
    cell.WordWrap = True          
    row.Cells.Add(cell)
    'row.Font = New Font("Segoe UI Light", 12, FontStyle.Regular)
    'row.ForeColor = Color.Gray
    row.Tag = extra
    Return row
End Function

'function for adding sender name and datetime
Function addHead(ByVal txt As String, ByVal extra As ChatExtraData) As Row
    Dim row As Row
    Dim cell As Cell

    row = New Row()
    cell = New Cell(txt)
    cell.WordWrap = False          
    row.Cells.Add(cell)
    row.Font = New Font("Segoe UI Light", 8, FontStyle.Bold)
    row.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 20, 133, 227)
    row.Tag = extra
    Return row
End Function
```

It's works but as I said some items are not visible and I can't scroll to them here attached a screenshot [some items aren't shown and I can't scroll anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4CUA.png)

Sorry for answering my own questions I haven't found another way to post code and image.
Waiting for help